# Style guide for c#?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I like style guide used by google for c++, published [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/) . Is there any similar style guide available for c# also? I'm looking for more of good practices along with simple things like naming just like in google style guide for c++.

Comment: updates? none of the answers here comes *any* close to the already pointed google's guide.

Answer (score 98):

I've been creating one for my development team by combining parts of all the good / great ones that I've been able to find.  Here are links to the ones I am using...

**Microsoft - Design Guidelines for Class Library Developers** - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx

**IDesign C# Coding Standard** - [http://www.idesign.net/idesign/download/IDesign CSharp Coding Standard.zip](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/download/IDesign%20CSharp%20Coding%20Standard.zip)

**SubMain C# / VB.NET Coding Guidelines** - http://submain.com/products/guidelines.aspx

**Lance Hunt - C# Coding Standards** - http://weblogs.asp.net/lhunt/archive/2004/08/17/CSharpCodingStandardsv113.aspx

**DotNetSpider - C# Coding Standards and Best Programming Practices** - http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/BestPractices.aspx

**Microsoft – C# Programming Guide** - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx

**Phillips Medical Systems - Coding Standard C#** - http://www.tiobe.com/content/paperinfo/gemrcsharpcs.pdf

Answer (score 20):

Microsoft has finally published [C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) used to develop documentation.
For naming conventions and design guidelines refer to [Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) by Microsoft.

Answer (score 8):

I have found IDesign to be one of the most comprehensive coding standards documents around. It covers things like naming conventions and other best practice elements. You can download a copy from here: [IDesign C# Coding Standard](http://www.idesign.net/Downloads/GetDownload/1985)

Comment: Just a question about IDesign: I clicked the link and the web page is asking me for my email along with a captcha. Looks kind of fishy to me. Is this how the web page is usually structured?

Comment: for anyone else who comes  here: just use a mailinator email address and download the zip file with pdfs

Answer (score 6):

You may want to have a look at [StyleCop](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop).

Answer (score 2):

See if [ICSharpCoding guideline](http://www.icsharpcode.net/technotes/sharpdevelopcodingstyle03.pdf) helps you. Otherwise if you are telling that you liked Google's C++ guideline, you can adopt it. Main point is that entire team is agreeing to it and following it.